# How to compare 4 column values of TAdvStringGrid with one another and label them?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

If i have colA, ColB, Colc, ColD and there are 1000 rows in each column in TAdvStringGrid . I would like check the number of double measurements of values in the 1000 rows in colA, ColB, Colc, ColD of TAdvStringGrid.

I am doing some thing like At first reading ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD values into multidimensional array and looping each element in multi dimensional array and comparing with each row element TAdvStringGrid and when found same using OnDrawcell function, I am labelling and displaying the row with a colour. 
However it takes a lot of time. Is there a shorter way to do it. As the rows keep on increasing. Thanks for the answer in advance.

---

Every row is one measurement and one measurement consist of 4 values in ColA,B, C,D.

```
List : array of array of double; 
SetLength (List,AdvStringGrid.RowCount,4);      
for i := 0 to AdvStringGrid.RowCount -1 do begin 
  j:=0; 
  List[i,j] := strtofloat(AdvStringGrid.Cells[4,i+1]); 
  List[i,j+1] := strtofloat(AdvStringGrid.Cells[5,i+1]); 
  List[i,j+2] := strtofloat(AdvStringGrid.Cells[8,i+1]); 
  List[i,j+3] := strtofloat(AdvStringGrid.Cells[9,i+1]); 
end;{for i}
```

How do i compare each element with neighbour and mark the duplicate??

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct that every row is one meassurement? So one meassurement consist out of 4 values?

First thing is you shouldn't modify the visual StringGrid in in a loop. In the worst case the StringGrid invalidates and draws again after each action.
So it's good to read all data in an multidimention array.

To eliminate doubles i would sort everything and then compare neigbors. This is a pretty common pattern.

Define any order like ColA accending, then ColB accending, ColC accending and ColD accending and implenent a sort algorithm (like quicksort or mergesort).

After everything is sortet you can traverse the array from highes element to 0 and check if two neighbours are the same.

If you want to mark the double values instead of deleting them consider adding a 5th colum for a value when it is a duplicate.

After all the calcilation i would search for any Function like `BeginUpdate()` and `Endupdate()` to make sure that the StringGrid will only draw once.

Do all changes to StringGrid between the call of `BeginUpdate()` and `Endupdate()`

**Update**: your code could look something like this:

```
var
 i:integer;
 sortedList: array of array of double;
begin
setlength(List, 1000, 5); // use a fifth row for marking doublicates, set this value to 0
// Fill List like you mentioned here
sortedList = YourSortAlgorithm(List); // sort your List here
for i := high(sortedList) downto 0 do
    begin
    // compare if entries are duplicates
    if sortedList[i,1] = sortedList[i-1,1] and sortedList[i,2] = sortedList[i-1,2] and sortedList[i,3] = sortedList[i-1,3] and sortedList[i,4] = sortedList[i-1,4] then
       begin
       sortedList[i-1,5] = 1; // 1 means duplicate, 0 means not duplicate
       end;
    end;
AdvStringGrid1.BeginUpdate;
// update your Stringgrid here
AdvStringGrid1.EndUpdate(); 
end;
```

Bye the way, instead of using a two dimentionaly array i would recoment to use a array of record.
Saying for example, that your ColA is a height, ColB is a length, ColC is a Temperature and ColD is a age you could define a record like this

```
type
TMeasurement = record
   height: double;
   length: double;
   temperature: double;
   age: double;
   isBoolean: boolean;
end; 

var
  list: array of TMeasurement;
begin
//...
end;
```

Comment: yes you are correct, Every row is one measurement and one measurement consist of 4 values in ColA,B, C,D. 
 List : array of array of double;  SetLength (List,AdvStringGrid.RowCount,4);
  for i := 0 to AdvStringGrid.RowCount -1 do
  begin
      j:=0;
      List[i,j] := strtofloat(AdvStringGrid.Cells[4,i+1]);
      List[i,j+1] := strtofloat(AdvStringGrid.Cells[5,i+1]);
      List[i,j+2] := strtofloat(AdvStringGrid.Cells[8,i+1]);
      List[i,j+3] := strtofloat(AdvStringGrid.Cells[9,i+1]);
  end;{for i}

How do i compare each element with neighbour and mark the duplicate??